# Configuring a gem-based model to be available to all sessions in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, configuration, rubygems

I am currently using the [mixpanel_client gem](https://github.com/keolo/mixpanel_client) to access the mixpanel API. I would like to be able to do this in one place:

```
config = {'api_key' => 'changeme', 'api_secret' => 'changeme'}
client = Mixpanel::Client.new(config)
```

and then access it anywhere throughout the app.  Is there an idiomatic (or framework-matic) way to go about this?  It seems like doing this everytime I want to make a request is a waste of resources and not very DRY to boot.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to do it, create an initializer, under initializer folder, so that it will be loaded once after rails is loaded, then

```
config = {'api_key' => 'changeme', 'api_secret' => 'changeme'}
CLIENT = Mixpanel::Client.new(config)
```

Then the CLIENT constant will be available anywhere in your app.

Else you can create a class

```
class MixPanelClient
 cattr_accessor: client

 def self.client
   client ||= begin
     config = {'api_key' => 'changeme', 'api_secret' => 'changeme'}
     Mixpanel::Client.new(config)
   end
 end
end
```

MixPanelClient.client would only create that client once.